Viessmann Combi Boiler - Tech Replaced Electrode Gasket with "Ultra Red"
I had an HVAC technician service my Viessmann Vitodens 100-W combi boiler today and I needed him to descale the inside of the system and do the regular maintenance. Unfortunately he didn't seem super familiar with the system, but seemed to be able to descale it OK.
Unfortunately when he turned the system back on, the Viessmann enclosure was getting super hot. He looked around and noticed that the gasket for the ignition system was cracked and he suspected that was causing the issue. He spent a lot of time complaining that the installer did not leave extra gaskets inside the system, which is true. He went to Home Depot and got "Permatex Ultra Red" which is a "high temp gasket maker" rated to 650°F. He put that on there (see picture) but said wait 24 hours for it to dry per the instructions.
I'm a bit nervous to turn it on tomorrow at the 24 hour mark. Is this a reasonable fix (even short-term)?
I ordered what I think are the right gaskets from Boston Heating Supply (below) but they will likely only arrive in 3 days. Please tell me what to do here. Is it OK to turn the system on?
http://bostonheatingsupply.com/7827024.aspxI had an HVAC technician service my Viessmann Vitodens 100-W combi boiler today and I needed him to descale the inside of the system and do the regular maintenance. Unfortunately he didn't seem super familiar with the system, but seemed to be able to descale it OK.
Unfortunately when he turned the system back on, the Viessmann enclosure was getting super hot. He looked around and noticed that the gasket for the ignition system was cracked and he suspected that was causing the issue. He spent a lot of time complaining that the installer did not leave extra gaskets inside the system, which is true. He went to Home Depot and got "Permatex Ultra Red" which is a "high temp gasket maker" rated to 650°F. He put that on there (see picture) but said wait 24 hours for it to dry per the instructions.
I'm a bit nervous to turn it on tomorrow at the 24 hour mark. Is this a reasonable fix (even short-term)?
I ordered what I think are the right gaskets from Boston Heating Supply (below) but they will likely only arrive in 3 days. Please tell me what to do here. Is it OK to turn the system on?
http://bostonheatingsupply.com/7827024.aspx

please proofread your post

Technically, Permatex RTV doesn't dry—it cures.
